# Asymptotics of the unique root of a polynomial equation defined as a sum of rational expressions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, asymptotics, continuity

Let $\lambda_1\ge \ldots \ge \lambda_n \gt 0$. Define a function $F:\mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ by

$$
F(t) = t^2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\lambda_i^2}{(\lambda_i + t)^2}.
$$

It is clear that $F$ is strictly increasing with supremum $F(\infty)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2=:M$. Let $0 \le s \le M$. It is clear that the equation $F(t) = s$ must have a unique solution $t(s)$ in $\mathbb R_+$.

For example, if $\lambda_i =1$, then $F(t) \equiv t^2M/(1+t)^2$. So, for every $0 \le s \le M$, we deduce that $t(s) = \sqrt{\epsilon/(1-\epsilon)}$, where $\epsilon := \sqrt{s/M}$.

Now, for varying $n$, let $n_1=n_1(n) \in [n]$ and $b=b(n) \in [0,1]$ be given, and set $\lambda_i = 1_{i \le n_1} + b1_{i \ge n_1+1}$ for all $i \in [n]$. For concreteness, you may take $n_1(n) \equiv 1$ and $b(n) \equiv 1/n$. Note that in this case, $M=n_1 + n_2 b$, where $n_2 := n - n_1$.

**Question.** Given $s=\epsilon^2 M$ with $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ fixed, is there an an asymptotically valid (in the limit $n \to \infty$) expression for $t_n(s)$ ?

I'd also be very interested in a systematic way of answering the above question for different choices of the sequences $n_1=n_1(n)$ and $b=b(n)$.

Comment: (i) Why do you need the $e_i$'s at all if you set them to $1$? (ii) If you fix $n_1$, why $n_1=n_1(n)$? (iii) Why not replace $b^2$ simply by, say, $c$? (iv) What is $\lambda_{i \ge n_1+1}$? Please reread your questions carefully before posting them.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup. Fixed.

Comment: In general, $F(\infty-) = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2\ne n$.

Comment: Typo: $n$ should be $M := \sum_i \lambda_i^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by analytic expression for $t(s)$? Do you mean a formula?

Comment: Yes, mean a simple formula: I know that it's a 4th degree equation and so can be solved via complicated expressions involving radicals (those are basically algorithms / recipies). I'm looking for something else. My hope is that the fact that $n \to \infty$ and the $\lambda_i$'s are in the example I gave, there will be some simplifications which lead to a simple analytic formula which is valid in an asymptotic sense. Finally, if the solutions of polynomial equations where continuous functions of their coefficients, life would be easy. But my understanding is that in general, they're not.

Comment: So with standard terminology, I think you mean an asymptotic formula, not an analytic formula.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Don't know why I used such a convoluted framing. Rectified.

Answer (score 1):

If the $\lambda_i$ take only two different values namely $\lambda_\max > \lambda_\min$, the equation $F(t)=s$ can be written
$$At^2(\lambda_\min+t)^2 + Bt^2(\lambda_\max+t)^2 = s (\lambda_\max+t)^2 (\lambda_\min+t)^2,$$ where $A$ and $B$ are positive constants with sum $M$. When $s \in~[0,M[$, this yields an algebraic equation with degree $4$, which is solvable by radicals. View https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation

Comment: Thanks for the input (upvoted). I know a 4th degree equation is solvable via radicals. I'm not interested in the formulae for the roots, but in their asymptotics in the settings specified in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If we know the dependency of $\lambda_i$ to $i$, it *could* be interesting to look at the zero of functions
$$f(t) = t^2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\lambda_i^2}{(t+\lambda_i )^2}-s\quad \quad \text{and}\quad\quad  g(t) = t^2\int_{1}^n\frac{\lambda_i^2}{(t+\lambda_i )^2}\,di-s$$ Using for example $\lambda_i=\frac 1i$
$$f(t)=\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{t}+1\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{t}+1+n\right)-\epsilon ^2 H_n^{(2)}\tag 1$$
$$g(t)=\frac{(n-1) t^2}{(t+1) (n t+1)}-\epsilon ^2 H_n^{(2)}\tag 2$$

Use $(2)$ to generate the estimate $t_0$ and perform one single iteration of Newton method. This would give
$$t_1=t_0-\frac{\epsilon ^2 H_n^{(2)}+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{t_0}+1+n\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{t_0}+1\right)}{\psi
   ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{t_0}+1\right)-\psi
   ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{t_0}+1+n\right)}\, t_0^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the input. That's an interesting approach. What are the $\psi$'s and $H$'s ? BTW,  along the lines of your approach: if $\lambda_i \asymp i^{-\beta}$ for some fixed $\beta \in (1,\infty)$, then one can  (looking at integrals instead of sums) show that $f(t) \asymp t^{1-1/\beta}$. In this case, we then have the analytic formula $t_\star \asymp \epsilon^{\beta/(\beta-1)}$, where $\epsilon := \sqrt{s/M}$.

Comment: @dohmatob. The polygamma functions and generalized harmonic numbers. I shall have a look at $\lambda_i=i^{-\beta}$. If anythig interesting, I shall edit. By the way, I faced very similar problems ... 50+ years ago ! You made me feeling youger. Cheers :-)

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying, and glad you find the question vaguely interesting.